# Pyspark - Apply groupBy aggregations on different group levels

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following pyspark dataframe:

```
+---------+-----+
|      Day|Sunny|
+---------+-----+
|   Sunday|  Yes|
|   Sunday|   No|
|   Monday|  Yes|
|   Monday|   No|
|  Tuesday|  Yes|
|  Tuesday|  Yes|
|  Tuesday|   No|
|  Tuesday|   No|
|  Tuesday|   No|
|Wednesday|  Yes|
|Wednesday|  Yes|
|Wednesday|  Yes|
|Wednesday|  Yes|
|Wednesday|   No|
| Thursday|  Yes|
| Thursday|  Yes|
| Thursday|   No|
| Thursday|   No|
|   Friday|   No|
|   Friday|   No|
|   Friday|  Yes|
| Saturday|  Yes|
| Saturday|  Yes|
| Saturday|   No|
+---------+-----+
```

I did a groupBy by the two columns `Day` and `Sunny` and then count, to get the count of each ("Day", "Sunny") pair:

```
+---------+-----+-----+
|      Day|Sunny|count|
+---------+-----+-----+
|   Friday|   No|    2|
|   Friday|  Yes|    1|
|   Monday|  Yes|    1|
|   Monday|   No|    1|
| Saturday|   No|    1|
| Saturday|  Yes|    2|
|   Sunday|   No|    1|
|   Sunday|  Yes|    1|
| Thursday|  Yes|    2|
| Thursday|   No|    2|
|  Tuesday|   No|    3|
|  Tuesday|  Yes|    2|
|Wednesday|  Yes|    4|
|Wednesday|   No|    1|
+---------+-----+-----+
```

My question is how do I get the following dataframe, that is adding a column of the percentage of each `Sunny` value count in each `Day` group:

```
+---------+-----+-----+---------------------+
|      Day|Sunny|count|                     |
+---------+-----+-----+---------------------+
|   Friday|   No|    2| 66% of Friday       |
|   Friday|  Yes|    1| 33% of Friday       |
|   Monday|  Yes|    1| 50% of Monday       |
|   Monday|   No|    1| 50% of Monday       |
| Saturday|   No|    1| 33% of Saturday     |
| Saturday|  Yes|    2| 66% of Saturday     |
|   Sunday|   No|    1| 50% of Sunday       |
|   Sunday|  Yes|    1| 50% of Sunday       |
| Thursday|  Yes|    2| 50% of Thursday     |
| Thursday|   No|    2| 50% of Thursday     |
|  Tuesday|   No|    3| 60% of Tuesday      |
|  Tuesday|  Yes|    2| 40% of Tuesday      |
|Wednesday|  Yes|    4| 80% of Wednesday    |
|Wednesday|   No|    1| 20% of Wednesday    |
+---------+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

The code for creating the dataframe is:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("Sunday", "Yes"),
        ("Sunday", "No"),
        ("Monday", "Yes"),
        ("Monday", "No"),
        ("Tuesday", "Yes"),
        ("Tuesday", "Yes"),
        ("Tuesday", "No"),
        ("Tuesday", "No"),
        ("Tuesday", "No"),
        ("Wednesday", "Yes"),
        ("Wednesday", "Yes"),
        ("Wednesday", "Yes"),
        ("Wednesday", "Yes"),
        ("Wednesday", "No"),
        ("Thursday", "Yes"),
        ("Thursday", "Yes"),
        ("Thursday", "No"),
        ("Thursday", "No"),
        ("Friday", "No"),
        ("Friday", "No"),
        ("Friday", "Yes"),
        ("Saturday", "Yes"),
        ("Saturday", "Yes"),
        ("Saturday", "No"),
    ],
    ["Day", "Sunny"]

)


df.groupBy(["Day", "Sunny"]).count().sort("Day").show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the total number of days (= `"count of (Fri, Yes)" + "count of (Fri, No)"`) to calculate the percentage, so you can get `sum` partitioned by `Day`.

```py
w = Window.partitionBy('Day')
df = df.withColumn('percentage', F.col('count') / F.sum(F.col('count')).over(w) * 100)
```

If you only want the integer, use floor/round to take out floating point.

```py
df = df.withColumn('percentage', F.floor(F.col('count') / F.sum(F.col('count')).over(w) * 100))
```